# How would I run command lines in Python?

Tags: python, command-line, module

I am playing around with this Instagram ID tracker because my friends are constantly changing usernames so I can never keep up. The code is from [here](https://github.com/th3unkn0n/osi.ig). The only way I am aware of, is that you have to go to any sort of terminal and type a command in this format

```
$ usage: t.py [-h] -u USERNAME [-p] [-s] [-t]
```

I've already tried to do some on my own and I recently saw other people running command lines in the Python text editor but it doesn't seem to work for me. This is what I did

```
import os
import main 
import api 

os.system('python3 main.py -u <USERNAME>')
```

There are 2 files, `main.py` and `api.py`. I imported both but when I run it, it still says

```
usage: t.py [-h] -u USERNAME [-p] [-s] [-t]
t.py: error: the following arguments are required: -u/--username
```

Is there an easier way to go about this?

Comment: Are you properly replacing `<USERNAME>` by the actual username you want to run this command against in `os.system('python3 main.py -u <USERNAME>')`

Comment: Yes. I just didn't want to put the actual username in there. But I am inputting the correct user

Comment: Dear Op, why do you wish to use `-u` ?

Comment: This code that I am currently using is not my own. And the owner just made it that way

Comment: Wadbo , I would reccommend doing away with the `-u <USERNAME>` and seeing if it runs alright ? (IMO, it should). Use only code you understand is good advice I got long back, and maybe it would be of use here :)

Comment: I wish that could've worked. But everything I've tried so far, gives me the same error everytime

Comment: @Wadbo I see little reason for `os.system('python3 main.py')` to not work

Comment: I imported `main` `api` and `os` and tried switching up the commands but it constantly gives me the same errors